# "Inherited from html" but still active in CSS inspector

Tags: html, css

If I write into my CSS the following code, in the Chrome inspector toolbox when I take a look to the Styles window, this rules are disabled by a `Inherited from html` but are still avalaible slightly higher.
Why ?

You can verificate by yourself :

```css
html, body{
 word-wrap:break-word;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #333;
}
```

```html
Inspect me
```

Comment: Inheritance relates to how HTML elements inherit CSS properties from their containing elements (ancestors). When the page loads the default last level parent element considered for inheritance is html, hence when you select the body it disables the inherited html's css styles since the body is contained within the <html>  in other words <html> related to body as an ancestral element, but if you try selecting <HTML> it wouldn't show the disabled styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you apply the styles to html *and* body. Html is the parent of body, so the styles will first be applied to html and passed on to it's child, the body. But then the browser overwrites those styles, this time because it is reading the body styles.

Basically what you are doing is short for:

```
html { word-wrap: break-word; /* etc */ }
body { word-wrap: break-word; /* etc */ }
```

Comment: So I just need to apply the rules to the html, no need to select the body ?

Comment: yes you can do that, and you may use body to further over ride styles. Or look at the following eg. the entire <body>  has a font-family of arial but a particular <h2> has a font-family of verdana. so although you can write body{font-family:arial} the same can be further overidden as h2{font-family:verdana} using specificity

Comment: I would  apply styles like color, word-wrap etc. to the body, instead of the html. It doesn't harm you in any sense when you apply them to both btw, so it's a bit arbitrary. However; apply them _at least_ to the body.

Comment: Yep I get it ;) But if I do html, body{ height: 100%;} , then there is no "inherited message". Strange no ?

Comment: Nope, that's not strange ;) That's because `height` is _not_ inherited by child elements. If it would, that would mean that every single `h1`, `img`, `p`, `span` etc. would also have `height: 100%` if you apply the height to the html element. That's not something you'd want, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

They are greyed out because you are not on that element. Try to select the html element in the dev tools and it will be black.